# Wordpress send Ajax where click button

Tags: ajax, javascript

I wanted to ask you, because I'm going crazy.

I am adding a form to save a file by ajax, from a modal, and I don't want to reload the page after sending, just reload the modal.

I have the following code:

```
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="envio_fichero_cita">
            Selecciona un archivo para cargarlo: =<?php echo($_POST['appt_id']); ?>
            <input type="file" id="file" name="file" /> <hr>
            <input type="hidden" id="appt_id" name="appt_id" value=<?php echo($_POST['appt_id']); ?> />

            <input type="button" id="enviar_fichero" value="Enviar archivo" />
            
        </form>
```

```
jQuery(function($) {

    $('body').on('change', '#file', function() {
        $this = $(this);
        var appt_id=document.getElementById('appt_id').value;
        file_data = $(this).prop('files')[0];
        form_data = new FormData();
        form_data.append('file', file_data);
        form_data.append('action', 'custom_ajax_booked_upload_files');
        form_data.append('appt_id', appt_id);
 
        $.ajax({
            url: ajax_var.url,
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data: form_data,
            success: function (response) {
                alert(response);
            }
        });
    });    
});
```

This code works correctly, but the sending by ajax is triggered when I select the file. What I want is for this to happen when I press the id="send_file" button.

I have tried to use the send form event, but it reloads the entire page, and it doesn't work for me.

Let's see if you could help me, so that the shipment is triggered when clicking on the button and not when selecting the file.

I have tried the following, but it doesn't fire it

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(e){
    // Submit form data via Ajax
    jQuery("#enviar_fichero").on('click', function() {
```

Thank you so much
Greetings

Comment: It's not clear what you want. You said " What I want is for this to happen when I press the id="send_file" button." But the button for the element with id "send_file" is the "Choose File" button when opens the select file window. Which you need to select the file you want to upload. But you added the submit Ajax code on the "onchange" event  of the of the element "send_file" 

Or maybe you're referring to the "Enviar archive" button and want to send the ajax when that button is clicked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@sergio

Here is the working answer you can check if there is still any issue paste it here and it if it works well you can upvote the answer to help others.

The issue it when you click button your $(this).prop('files')[0] is not working because not this scope to the button element.

```
$('body').on('click', '#enviar_fichero', function() {
        $this = $(this);
        var appt_id=document.getElementById('appt_id').value;
        file_data = jQuery('#file').prop('files')[0];
        form_data = new FormData();
        form_data.append('file', file_data);
        form_data.append('action', 'custom_ajax_booked_upload_files');
        form_data.append('appt_id', appt_id);
         
        $.ajax({
             url: ajax_var.url,
             type: 'POST',
             contentType: false,
             processData: false,
             data: form_data,
             success: function (response) {
                alert(response);
            }
      });
});
```

Comment: This did work!!

Thanks a lot